# Random number getting appended to the file names contained in the zip while rendering from Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, zip

I am trying to create a zip file out of a list of files and render the zip in the Spring Boot application. I am pasting code snippet for the same below for better understanding:

```
public static ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody>
      getZippedResponseFromFiles(List<File> fileList) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
    headers.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=results.zip");
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
        .headers(headers)
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
        .body(out -> {
          var zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(out);
          for (File file : fileList) {
            zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(file.getName()));
            try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file)) {
              IOUtils.copy(fileInputStream, zipOutputStream);
            }
            zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
          }
          zipOutputStream.close();
        });
  }
```

Here everything is working fine, except a random number getting appended to the file names contained in the zip. I cannot understand how to fix this.

Could anyone please help here? Thanks.

**EDIT**

I probably understood where the problem is. Following is the code snippet to download the s3 object and store it in a file:

```
public File downloadObject(String filePath) {
    File file = null;
    try {
      file = File.createTempFile(filePath, "");
      file.deleteOnExit();
      amazonS3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, filePath), file);
    } catch (SdkClientException exception) {
      throw new TcBadServerStateException(ErrorCodeEnum.AWS_SERVICE_ERROR, exception);
    } 
    return file;  <--THE FILE HAS THE RANDOM NUMBER APPENDED TO FILENAME
  }
```

Here in the file, that being returned from this function, the random number getting appended to the file name. I am not getting any idea, how to fix this.

Comment: @IłyaBursov Sorry, it was a typo. But, I am not able to figure out, how to get rid of the random numbers appended to the file names.

Comment: Have checked that the random numbers aren't there already?  Are you sure that the way you are reading / checking the generated zip file is correct?

Comment: ... because I can't see any way that this code could add random numbers (or non-random numbers) to the filenames.

Comment: Is the underlying file hierarchy changing?  A possible scenario is an NFS mount where files are deleted with open handles forcing the NFS server to rename the file.

Comment: Hi, @StephenC yeah, I have checked. Actually, I am downloading the files from s3 and create a zip containing them. None of them has any numbers appended to them.

Comment: And what about at the other end?  How are you checking the generated ZIP has numbers appended to the filenames?  (I say this because in the ZIP file format there is stuff after the file name that you could be misinterpreting ... depending on how you are reading / examining  the ZIP file; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)#File_headers)

Comment: @StephenC Actually I found, how the random number is getting appended to the end of the file name. But I am not able to figure out, how to get rid of this.